# Executing a task at particular time interval

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee, executorservice

I want to schedule a task in `java` which runs in every 2 min. The task should run on every 2 min even though previous task is not yet finished. (I.e.  next task executing parallel to previous incomplete task.)
Is there any way of doing this in java or in spring?

Comment: You can use TimerTask. Quartz scheduler is also an option. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is not an option since you want the next task to run even if the previous task has not finished.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Quartz Scheduler](https://quartz-scheduler.org/) for this. It allows you to schedule a task to run at an interval (in miliseconds) or on a predefined date and time (for as long as specified) based on a `CRON` expression.

You can find the documentation for this here:
https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation

If `Quartz` isn't an option, there is a long, comprehensive list of alternatives at java-source.net on *"Open Source Job Schedulers in Java"* :

http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @user4325796 You're welcome - Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are looking for a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

> An ExecutorService that can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.
>
> The schedule methods create tasks with various delays and return a task object that can be used to cancel or check execution. The **scheduleAtFixedRate** and scheduleWithFixedDelay methods create and execute tasks that run periodically until cancelled.

Comment: Hi, scheduleAtFixedRate java doc itself saying that next task might delay depending upon execution of previous task but both cannot run in concurrent way.